# Some problems when I build gcc4.4.0 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, build

I try to build gcc 4.4.0 with source code on ubuntu 14.04.
my configuration is:

```
configure -v --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/exe
```

Soon I encountered a series of errors such as

```
error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
error: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
error: bits/errno.h: No such file or directory
```

After searching, it was found that the missing file is located in

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

So I copied them to `/usr/include/` directory to solve the problem.

Then compile smoothly until it appears

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
```

Although this problem can be solved by `export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

But I used the same compiler and configuration in Red Hat Enterprise 7 without any problems.
Does anyone know why this problem occur?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are missing the "build prerequisites" `sudo apt install g++ flex bison gettext dejagnu sharutils texinfo doxygen binutils-dev elfutils libelf-dev`

Comment: ? May be gcc-4.4.0 is too old to find the new locations? `crti.o`  etc. are in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` . .... gcc requires a build folder outside gcc-4.4.0/ : `../gcc-4.4.0/configure --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib` ( + your PREFIX ).

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise (7) did not change locations. Has always been  `/usr/lib64, /usr/include/`